# php signature output in a copy'able string

Tags: php, encryption, public-key-encryption

I need to copy paste the signature of a specific input in PHP, there are no errors but the resulting signature is a bunch of symbols and not alphanumeric characters, I highly assume its because I am missing some encoding somewhere.

This is my code:

```
<?php 

$unformatted_pub= "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$unformatted_priv = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

$data = '1234';

// compute signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $unformatted_priv);

echo $signature;

?>
```

And this is the result:

���3��TQW<*�^�T�Kd�i�hF�X�:0��d�GޱE�)�z9H������ө%CO��H�m˻J@���'6�>�Q�vn�r�&��絛k�=�X��_�ꗼ*������1oK�3�1���&�EI��=�����}]Qo��u 4�'�\� �l��u��/������q�%���2�����)��3+����`��q҃|I�Of֯\�|e�h��u�i�"[Mjtc���"�^���j"s8��'���Y���upW9���1�#��CB�͇�f�ߩ�Hn�N�KF�@,e�݇��7�� �� aIB?.v#���Q�j>z4� ���/s����͇����uߌ,�u��!ᄃ���+"� uO  �{��O3]���h}�- �|�s����;F;�ɣj�x�O=�aw$�Jz7� (ѬJbN�T�?(<��}X%������*��!y\V�5u���_C�K��s*��<}�M|#w��?�mey�

Lastly, I tried to verify the signature which returns True, so there are no errors, I just want the signature in a format where I can copy and paste it.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo base64_encode($signature);
```

Comment: this is the right way to encode a binary data output for being copyable

Comment: Perfect, and i assume when I want to verify it I will use decode right?

Comment: Yes. for my application it's working perfect without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP docs example suggests the best way is to save signature to a file instead of copying it.

```
//create signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key_pem);

//save for later
file_put_contents('private_key.pem', $private_key_pem);
file_put_contents('public_key.pem', $public_key_pem);
file_put_contents('signature.dat', $signature);

//verify signature
$r = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key_pem);
var_dump($r);
```

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately that is not possible.

Comment: Then I suggest second answer with echo base64_encode($signature); and then decode it when you need to use it.